# How can I replace if statements with ternary operators in React?

Tags: reactjs, operator-keyword, ternary

I'm beginner in ReactJS and I have trouble with ternary operators.

I can't find better solution for using ternary operator(? :) in this code, when I try, I receive errors or my code is not working (not showing type).

My code with (if else) everything working:

```
const TypeChecker = (product) => {
    if (
      product.width === null &&
      product.length === null &&
      product.height === null
    ) {
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          Dimensions: {product.width} x {product.length} x {product.height}
        </div>
      );
    }

    if (product.size === null) {
    } else {
      return <div>Size: {product.size} MB</div>;
    }

    if (product.weight === null) {
    } else {
      return <div>Weight: {product.weight} KG</div>;
    }
  };
```

```
 return (
    <div>
      <div className="productContainer">
        {products.map((product, key) => (
          <div key={key} className="productCard" id="product">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={handleChange}
              id="delete-checkbox"
              value={product.id}
              className="removeCardCheckbox cardItem delete-checkbox"
            />

            <div className="cardItem">{product.sku}</div>
            <div className="cardItem">{product.name}</div>
            <div className="cardItem">{product.price} $</div>
        
              {TypeChecker(product)} //Here show type if it no null

            <div className="CardButtons">
              <button
                onClick={() => deleteProduct(product.id)}
                className="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2"
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
```

For example with ternary operator one of checker:

```
 product.width === null &&
    product.length === null &&
    product.height === null ? (
      console.log("This is furniture")
    ) : (<div>
        Dimensions: {product.width} x {product.length} x {product.height}
      </div>)
```

in this case I receive error Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.jsxDEV)(...) is not a function

Please help me to understand what is my mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to turn that entire function into a ternary conditional expression...

First, invert your conditions.  Structures like this are strange and are making your code more difficult to modify/support (as you're discovering):

```
if (product.size === null) {
} else {
  return <div>Size: {product.size} MB</div>;
}
```

There's no reason to *always* put logic in the `else` block.  An `if` block can and should contain logic.  So change the above to this:

```
if (product.size !== null) {
  return <div>Size: {product.size} MB</div>;
}
```

Do the same thing for the other conditions.  Then your function is essentially three conditional `return` statements.  Which can be turned into one `return` statement with chained conditional operators:

```
const TypeChecker = (product) =>
  (product.width !== null || product.length !== null || product.height !== null) ?
    (<div>Dimensions: {product.width} x {product.length} x {product.height}</div>) :
  (product.size !== null) ?
    (<div>Size: {product.size} MB</div>) :
  (product.weight !== null) ?
    (<div>Weight: {product.weight} KG</div>) :
    null;
```

Whether or not that's *more readable* or easier to modify/support than the original (after inverting the conditions of course) is a matter of opinion.  There's really no need to convert all conditional code into ternary conditional expressions.  The latter is not a drop-in replacement for the former.

Comment: Many thanks, now I little understand logic, but I still have error 
Line 35:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions @David

Comment: @TimPonarenko: Looks like I had a typo and forgot to close one of the parentheses.  I've corrected it.  (Which is another reason why this version isn't necessarily "better" because such structural problems are less obvious.)

Comment: I find this close, but still error, in this case no problem I will use inverted value of If, thank you some much